# Positive Measure of Limsup of Subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf

Given a measure space $\Omega$, a sequence of measurable functions $(f_n : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R})_{n=1}^\infty$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}$, such that:

$\{ \omega \in \Omega : \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(\omega) > r \}$

has positive measure. Is it possible to find a subsequence of arbitrarily fast growing indices, such that this set still has positive measure?

To be more precise, imagine also being given a sequence $(N_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ of natural numbers. Does there always exist a sequence of natural numbers $(n_k)_{k=1}^\infty$ satisfying:

1. $n_k \geq N_k$, for all $k \in \mathbb{N}^{\geq 1}$
2. $\{ \omega \in \Omega :\lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} (\sup \{f_{n_K}, f_{n_{K+1}}, f_{n_{K+2}}, …\}(\omega))> r \}$

has positive measure?